# XPath using iTextSharp and C#

Tags: c#, xpath

I have an xml file in the below format which is generated dynamically.

```
 <emp>
    <id>1</id>
    <Name>aaa</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
</emp>    
<emp>
    <id>2</id>
    <Name>bbb</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
</emp>
<emp>
    <id>3</id>
    <Name>ccc</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
</emp>
```

I am trying to select Name element from the xml document. Based on number on occurrences of emp, I am using below code.

For single occurence, below code works fine..

```
XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode("//t:*[@name='" + Name + "']");
```

For multiple emp occurrence, looping through repeating elements. Below code is not working.

```
XMLDocument.SelectNodes("//t:*[@name='emp[" + i + "]/" + Name + "']");
```

Any suggestions or correction in my code please.

Comment: When using `SelectNodes` do not use the `Name` attribute, because you get a collection of all the nodes with this ID. In such case `Name` must correlate with `id`.

Comment: No luck, can you provide an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("xmlFileLocation");
int id = 2; //Required input from the user
XmlNode idNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//emp/id[.=" + "'" + id + "']");
if(idNode != null)
   Console.WriteLine( "Employee " + idNode.InnerText + " has name : " + idNode.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText);
```

Output is :

```
Employee 2 has name : bbb
```

It works as  : for `id = 2`, the xpath gets the `id` node and from there go to parent and get the name.

Comment: My requirement is NOT for all employees, its only for emp of i value.
For example when i is 2, I need only name of second emp.